# Clojurescript Om password field issue in firefox

Tags: firefox, clojurescript

I am having a weird issue rendering a password field inside a form which happens only in firefox

This code is given below:

```
(ns app.user
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
        [om.dom :as dom :include-macros true]
        [goog.dom :as gdom]))

(def password-data (atom {}))

(defn password-input [data owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [this]
      (dom/form #js {}
            (dom/input #js {:type "password" :id "test-password"})

            (dom/input #js {:type "password" :id "confirm-password"})))))


(om/root password-input password-data
           {:target (gdom/getElement "test")})
```

The issue is, the first password field inside the form is auto-filled with value "password".

My firefox version is 33.0 on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution since then?

Comment: @leontalbot Not really. Switched to Reagent which I found easier to use.

Comment: Also the my latest version of firefox (developer edition 37.0a2) doesn't seem to have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the firefox doesn't seem to have an issue. In older version I find changing

```
(dom/form
```

to

```
(dom/div
```

fixed the issue.

P.S I switched to reagent which is simpler than Om